# How to get increment number when there are any change in a column in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data `date, id, and flag` on this table. How I can get the `value` column where this column is incremental number and reset from 1 when there are any change in `flag` column?

[image: my table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(changed, grp),
  row_number() over(partition by id, grp order by date) value
from (
select *, countif(changed) over(partition by id order by date) grp
from (
  select *,
    ifnull(flag != lag(flag) over(partition by id order by date), true) changed
  from `project.dataset.table`
))
```

if applied to sample data in your question  - output is

[image]

Comment: very good pattern, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to count the number of `false`s since the last `true`.  You can use:

```
select t.* except (grp),
       (case when flag
             then 1
             else row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by date) - 1
        end)
from (select t.*,
             countif(flag) over (partition by id order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you know that the dates have no gaps, you can actually do this without a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag then 1
             else date_diff(date,
                            max(case when flag then date end) over (partition by id),
                            day)
        end)
from t;
```